# OnItemClick events of listview depending on where I clicked

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView looking like this:

[image: listview]

Each list element is composed of a relative layout with two image buttons and a textview.

Right now clicking on each list element highlights the background of the list element (relative layout background). This done using a `onItemClickListener` callback. However clicking anywhere on the listview will still trigger the callback and change the background colour.
  Is there a way to:

1. If I click on the image buttons where one will be upvote and one will be downvote somehow handle this event differently? Specifically instead of changing the background of the whole list element I would like just the upvote button to respond
2. If I click anywhere else in the list element (excluding the two buttons) I would like the onItemClick event to fire normally changing the background of the whole list element.

The listener right now:

```
public class TsClickListener implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        view.setSelected(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Set appropriate `OnClickListener`s on the `ImageButton`s in your Adapter's `getView()` method.

Comment: Create you buttons and textviews dynamicly then add them to your relativeLayout dynamicly as well.(I use linearlayout, for example ı give 5 weightsum it and add my items  with 1 weight,if max size 5).then create your textwatcher in your class.(inner class textwatcher). I wish I could help you more but not enough time at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setup two seperate onClickListener() for the View and the ImageButton like this,

For ImageView,

```
ImageButton iv = view.findViewById(R.id.ivHello);
iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //ImageButton is now clicked
            }
        });
```

And for your regular view,

```
 view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //View is now clicked
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

try this if it works

```
ImageView imageBtnUp = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageBtnup);
ImageView imageBtnDown = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageBtndown);

imageBtnUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
// apply your functionality here for first button
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });

imageBtnDown.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
// apply your functionality here for Down button
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the same onClickListener for image buttons and list elements, you can use `instanceof` operator in you onClickListener, so you will be able to distinguish whether the ImageButton or TextView was clicked.

```
public class TsClickListener implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if(view instanceof ImageButton) {
            // upvote/downvote stuff
        }
        else if(view instanceof TextView) {
            view.setSelected(true);
        }
    }
}
```